# Calibrate + able = Calibratible? Calibratable?

Tags: suffixes

What is the consensus on the correct form of calibrate + able suffix? [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/calibratable) lists only one proper entry for "calibratable". Automotive industries prefer to use "calibratible" because it matches the pronunciation (disclaimer: I work in one). Neither are accepted by spell-checkers.

Any thoughts or opinions?

Comment: Google Books claims 2,100 results for [calibratable](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22calibratable%22), against only 121 for [calibratible](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22calibratible%22). Go with the majority, and don't expect spell-checkers to include every possible "word". In my pronunciation, the last vowel is a neutral schwa anyway. Are you sure you're not being influenced by what your colleagues *write*, rather than what you *hear/say?*

Comment: To add to the confusion, I've also seen "calibrable", which apparently is mostly used in theoretical mathematics.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That’s because one never adds *-ible* to first-conjugation verbs like *calibrate*.

Answer (score 4):

The only [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=calibratible%2Ccalibratable%2Ccalibrateable%2Ccalibrable&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccalibratable%3B%2Cc0) that yields any results from *calibrable, calibratable, calibriable and calibrateable* is *calibratable*. It also has a [Wiktionary entry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/calibratable). However, the paraphrasation is a lot [more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=calibratable%2C+can+be+calibrated&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccalibratable%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccan%20be%20calibrated%3B%2Cc0). So unless you absolutely need a single word, just write *can be calibrated.*

If you do need a single word, everything points to calibratable. [The University of Michigan considers it a word.](https://books.google.de/books?id=O44gAAAAMAAJ&q=%22calibratable%22&dq=%22calibratable%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiEpKWFv5nPAhUJVhoKHay0DnQQ6AEIOTAE)